# How to prevent the Windows 10 Anniversary update from reinstalling Modern apps?

Tags: modern-ui, windows-10-v1607

Since I've installed the Anniversary update on my work computer it's been reinstalling all those Modern apps like Connect, Microsoft WiFi, and Phone.

Since I have no use for them I used to turn off the "Consumer Experience" option in Group Policy Editor and then uninstalling them but it seems this new release deprecated the setting and only allows to choose whether to install Microsoft apps or third-party ones as well (at least Candy Crush isn't back... *yet*).

In the meantime I'm using the commands from [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/611049) in a daily scheduled task but it seems like it has no effect and the garbage keeps coming back.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Group Policy settings are ignored for Home/Pro since 1607. they only work for enterprise/education editions. ms want to push users to use store apps

Comment: @magicandre1981 indeed i've noticed that. However I have no desire to use them and would like them gone. Looking for a hack/workaround just like for the lockscreen.

Comment: ok, I found a new hack in the web. Try it.

Comment: The hack is for Enterprise. The blog post is plain wrong.

Comment: @Daniel AppLocker is part of Pro: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5749744/Bilder/superuser/applocker.png

Comment: @magicandre1981 [read and comprehend](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/Compare) ... 'nuff said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Winaero.com found a hack](http://winaero.com/blog/stop-windows-10-anniversary-update-from-installing-candy-crush-and-other-unwanted-apps/) on [MDL](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/70825-Windows-10-Pro-Group-Policy-Fix) that uses AppLocker to block the apps:

- Run secpol.msc (<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>)
- Select Application Control Policies in the left, then click Applocker.

[image]

- Right click  the right pane and select Create new rule:

[image]

- On the Permissions page, set Action to `Deny`, leave User or Group as `Everyone`:

[image]

- Click Next, then click `Use an installed packaged app as a reference` -> `Select`:

[image]

- In the app list, select `Windows Spotlight(Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager)` and click OK:

[image]

- Move the slider to the Package Name option as shown below, then click `Create`:

[image]

> Note that already downloaded content in the tiles wont go away after
>   this Applocker rule, however, there will not be any new content after
>   this. You can remove existing unwanted apps. All you need to do is
>   right click their tiles and remove them, they won't coming back.

Comment: Applocker is an Enterprise/Education feature. And if you use Enterprise/Education, you could also just use the Group Policy setting.

Comment: @Daniel this does indeed work on Pro.